# How can I create a random number between two entry field numbers in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Okay, here is another idiotic question: I have two entry fields and the idea is to insert a random number into a third entry field. I want that the random number comes from between the two entry fields' values.
For example: I type in number 1 into the first entry field and a number 10 into the second. As I press the button, I want it to create the random number from between those 1 and 10 and insert it into the third field. (I'm sorry if this is confusing, I tried my best explaining) Here's some code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Entry, END, E, W
from random import randint, randrange

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Number Generator')

e1 = Entry(root, font=("LEMON MILK Bold", 24), width=10, borderwidth=10)
e1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

e2 = Entry(root, font=("LEMON MILK Bold", 24), width=5, borderwidth=10)
e2.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

e3 = Entry(root, font=("LEMON MILK Bold", 24), width=5, borderwidth=10)
e3.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=E)

#Definitions

def button_generate():
    e1.delete(0, END)
    e1.insert(randint(e2.get, e3.get))

def button_clear():
    e1.delete(0, END)

#Buttons

button_generate = tkinter.Button(root, text="Random number", font=("LEMON MILK Bold", 28), padx=20, 
pady=10, command=button_generate)
button_clear = tkinter.Button(root, text="Erase", font=("LEMON MILK Bold", 14), padx=22, pady=5, 
command=button_clear)
button_exit = tkinter.Button(root, text="Exit", font=("LEMON MILK Bold", 14), padx=15, pady=5, 
command=root.quit)

#Grid

button_generate.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3)
button_clear.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_exit.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `e2.get()`, for example, not `e2.get`.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? - Making a random number? Responding to the button click? Inserting the random number?

Comment: @wwiii I'm having trouble with the part where I insert the 1 and 10 to the entry fields, and I click the button, but it gives me an error and it doesn't insert the random number between 1 and 10 to the third entry field.

Comment: `gives me an error ` - When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)
.

Comment: Always show the error. Oh, and this: `r2.get` is the get method. You want to call that method, not use the method itself as a parameter.

Comment: @wwii I'm very new to Stackoverflow, so I didn't know this, but I'll keep this in mind in my future questions! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `e2.get` is a method, you wouldn't get the content in the entry.Like jasonharper pointed out in the comment, it should be `e2.get()`.
2. Also, `entry.get()` will return a string instead of a number. to generate random number by `random.randint`, you need to convert it to a number.
3. `entry.insert()` need a index argument,you didn't pass that, so the function should be change to:

```
def button_generate():
    e1.delete(0, END)
    e1.insert(END, randint(int(e2.get()), int(e3.get())))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issues are with the [`insert`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.insert-method) method. The first argument of the method is the `index`, you should provide one. The second argument is the string you want to enter. This string is generated by the `randint` method. This method asks for two integers. You should get the values from `e2` and `e3` and convert them to integers.

The `button_generate` function should be :

```
  def button_generate():
      e1.delete(0, END)
      e1.insert(0,randint(int(e2.get()), int(e3.get())))
```